# Defining the format for Author misaligns the footnotes

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes, alignment

I am working on my thesis (in french) and using Biblatex with [geschichtsfrkl](https://ctan.org/pkg/geschichtsfrkl?lang=en) as the style for defining citations in the footnotes.

In addition to the normal footnotes (executed through `\footnote{}`), I am often using `\footcite[][]{}` to cite articles/books.

The geschichtsfrkl style adds a comma between the LastName and FirstName of authors. However, since my university asks that there must be no comma in between them, I updated the style using the following code:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{
\nameparts{#1}%
{\autorenschriftart%
\ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
\namepartfamily
}%
\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\space%
\ifbool{bbx:nurinit}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartgiven}}%
\isdot%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
{\autorentrennzeichen\addspace}{}%
}%
```

But, doing so destroys the alignment of the footnotes and adds an extra space before the author name. Please check the following image for the problem (13 and 16 are citations and others are normal footnotes). I problem of alignment happens only with citations and not with normal footnotes.

[image]

I haven't so far managed to fix this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks for help in advance :)

Following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    french,
    10 pt,              
    openright
]{article}              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl,
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{
\nameparts{#1}%
{\autorenschriftart%
\ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
\namepartfamily
}%
\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\space%
\ifbool{bbx:nurinit}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartgiven}}%
\isdot%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
{\autorentrennzeichen\addspace}{}%
}%

\addbibresource{\thesis.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\thesis.bib}

@article{deroudille2019extraterritorialite,
  title={L’extraterritorialit{\'e} du RGPD dans le contexte du “Cloud Act”},
  author={Deroudille, Alexis and Fatah, Farid},
  journal={Revue du marche commun et de l'Union Europ{\'e}enne},
  number={630},
  pages={442--452},
  year={2019},
  publisher={{\'E}ditions Techniques et Economiques}
}

@article{decaux1987application,
  title={L'application extraterritoriale du droit {\'e}conomique},
  journal = {Cahiers du Centre de Droit International de Nanterre},
  number = {3},
  author={Decaux, Emmanuel},
  year={1987},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{lehmann_m_legal_2017,
    title = {Legal fragmentation, extraterritoriality and uncertainty in global financial regulation},
    volume = {37},
    issn = {0143-6503},
    %language = {English},
    number = {2},
    journal = {Oxford Journal of Legal Studies},
    author = {{Lehmann}, Matthias},
    pages = {406-434},
    year = {2017},
    note = {OCLC: 7086651768},
    pages = {406--434}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text\footcite[Sample Pre-text][Post-text]{lehmann_m_legal_2017}, then some more text without pre- and post-notes\footcite[][]{decaux1987application}, and now a normal footnote\footnote{Hello world!}. One more citation just in case\footcite[][]{deroudille2019extraterritorialite}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are adding a space here `\DeclareNameFormat{author}{` (no `%`)

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, it does solve the problem. Many thanks :) Also, the solution proposed by moewe works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) has already pointed out the issue with the code in the comments: You are missing a `%` sign in the very first line. `\DeclareNameFormat{author}{` should read `\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%`.

Let me just say that the way `geschichtsfrkl` handles the name formatting and thus also the redefinition from the question is quite non-standard.

A similar result can be achieved using the following more standard methods.

```
\documentclass[
    french,
    10pt,
    openright
]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl,
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{{\autorenschriftart #1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\autorentrennzeichen\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{deroudille2019extraterritorialite,
  title={L’extraterritorialit{\'e} du RGPD dans le contexte du “Cloud Act”},
  author={Deroudille, Alexis and Fatah, Farid},
  journal={Revue du marche commun et de l'Union Europ{\'e}enne},
  number={630},
  pages={442--452},
  year={2019},
  publisher={{\'E}ditions Techniques et Economiques}
}
@article{decaux1987application,
  title={L'application extraterritoriale du droit {\'e}conomique},
  journal = {Cahiers du Centre de Droit International de Nanterre},
  number = {3},
  author={Decaux, Emmanuel},
  year={1987},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
@article{lehmann_m_legal_2017,
    title = {Legal fragmentation, extraterritoriality and uncertainty in global financial regulation},
    volume = {37},
    issn = {0143-6503},
    %language = {English},
    number = {2},
    journal = {Oxford Journal of Legal Studies},
    author = {{Lehmann}, Matthias},
    pages = {406-434},
    year = {2017},
    note = {OCLC: 7086651768},
    pages = {406--434}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite[Sample Pre-text][Post-text]{lehmann_m_legal_2017},
then some more text without pre- and post-notes\footcite{decaux1987application}, 
and now a normal footnote\footnote{Hello world!}.
One more citation just in case\footcite{deroudille2019extraterritorialite}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes without undesirable space.]

Comment: Dear @moewe thanks for this non-traditional solution. It works perfectly as does David's solution. Many thanks :)